# How can I create online leaderboards for iOS and Android?

Tags: c#, android, monogame, ios

I'm developing a racing game for iOS and Android phones/tablets and I want to implement online leaderboards. My game has a singleplayer mode(no multiplayer features) but I want to implement online leaderboards to encourage people to beat other player's score and time.

I want to save the score and time(the time that you need to finish the race) in an online leaderboard. In addition, the name of the player and if possible his country are also saved in the leaderboard. The leaderboards don't need to be cross platform, I can create two leaderboards, one for iOS and one for Android.

Is it possible to create online leaderboards without MySQL and PHP knowledge? In addition, I don't have a server to save the data.

I use MonoGame to develop my game. Do you know a step by step tutorial for implementing online leaderboards because I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at globalstats.io (https://globalstats.io). It is a hobby project I am running for some time now that offers free leaderbords for your exact use case.